# Apagar dados duplicados mais antigos em MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, delete

Estou com um problema, em uma tabela que tem dados duplicados. Os dados duplicados é identificado através de um ID, em que cada linha tem o identificador e um data, como é que eu posso apagar todos os dados  com mais de 1 registo da na tabela, deixar apenas o registo mais recente?

A base de dados é um MS SQL SERVER, ou seja, o script dever fazer com que, na lista abaixo, elimina as 4 linhas mais antigas:

```
ID            DATA
17081618585 | 18.02.02 18:42:41
17081618585 | 18.02.02 19:30:41
17081618585 | 18.02.02 20:42:41
17081618585 | 18.02.02 20:42:41
17081618585 | 18.02.02 22:42:42
```

Comment: no caso iria ficar somente `17081618585 | 18.02.02 22:42:42`?

Answer (score 4):

Uma abordagem simples é utilizar uma `CTE` (*Common Table Expression*) para selecionar os registros que você **NÃO** quer excluir. Depois disso, é só fazer um DELETE com join com a `CTE` criada para apagar os registros.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
with cte as (
    select id,max(data) max_data
    from #teste
    group by id
)
delete t
from #teste t
inner join cte
on  (t.id = cte.id)
and (t.data <> cte.max_data)
```

A `CTE` selecione a data máxima por ID. Depois disso, é feito um DELETE na tabela em questão e no join especifica-se que a data a ser deletada deve ser diferente da data da CTE.

**Um detalhe**: para que isso funcione o campo que armazena a data precisa, necessariamente, ser uma data no SQL Server, ou seja, um campo do tipo `datetime` ou afim. Se for um campo `varchar` então o `max` que está na `CTE` falhará.

Comment: Solução excelente! Depois disso seria bom criar uma constraint com PK no ID(por exemplo), pra evitar essa situação futuramente já que a tabela não deve ter ID's duplicados.